# Showing ads in RecyclerView paging with Firestore database

Tags: android, firebase, android-recyclerview, pagination

I am working with RecyclerView which support pagination with Firestore database.I want to showing into 10 items recylcerview an Ads,i try serveral times without succes,help me please to find the right code.

Here is my code of pagination.

```
     //Initialize FirebasePagingOptions
    DatabasePagingOptions<Pubs> options = new DatabasePagingOptions.Builder<Pubs>()
            .setLifecycleOwner(this)
            .setQuery(mDatabase, config, Pubs.class)
            .build();
    //Initialize Adapter
    mAdapter = new FirebaseRecyclerPagingAdapter<Pubs, PubsViewHolder>(options) {
        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position)
        {
            if (position % 5 == 0)
                return AD_TYPE;
            return CONTENT_TYPE;
        }
        @NonNull
        @Override
        public PubsViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
            return new PubsViewHolder(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_pub, parent, false));
        }

        @Override
        protected void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull PubsViewHolder holder,
                                        int position,
                                        @NonNull Pubs model) {
            holder.setItem(model);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

this is a full example to how to use **multi type** `recyclerview` with **custom adapter** with **Model** and **Ads** Type
and for paging issue you have to handle it **outside** adapter class it can be more easier.

```
public class SiteAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {
    private List<SiteModel> dataList;
    private Context context;

    private static final int AD_TYPE = 1;
    private static final int CONTENT_TYPE = 2;

    public SiteAdapter(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
        dataList = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemViewType(int position) {
        if (dataList.get(position) == null)
            return AD_TYPE;
        return CONTENT_TYPE;
    }



    public List<SiteModel> getDataList() {
        return dataList;
    }



    @NonNull
    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View v = null;

        RecyclerView.ViewHolder vh = null;
        if (viewType == AD_TYPE) {
            v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.ad_view_item, parent, false);
            vh = new AdViewHolder(v);

        } else {
            v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.site_list_item, parent, false);
            vh = new SitesViewHolder(v);
        }
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        holder.setIsRecyclable(false);

        if (getItemViewType(position) == CONTENT_TYPE) {

        } else {
            AdViewHolder adViewHolder = (AdViewHolder) holder;
            AdRequest request = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
            adViewHolder.adView.loadAd(request);
        }
    }


    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return dataList.size();
    }

    public void add(SiteModel siteModel, int i) {
        dataList.add(siteModel);
        notifyItemInserted(i);
    }

    public void add(List<SiteModel> moreData) {
        dataList.addAll(moreData);
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }


    public void updateItem(String desc, boolean isFavourites, int adapterPosition) {
        dataList.get(adapterPosition).setDesc(desc);
        notifyItemChanged(adapterPosition);
    }


    public class SitesViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {




        public SitesViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);


        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (clickListener != null) {
                switch (v.getId()) {


            }
        }
    }



    private class AdViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

        AdView adView;

        public AdViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            adView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

        }
    }
}
```